# Whose portrait is printed on the Waterdhavian gold coin?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms, lore, waterdeep-dragon-heist

Reading *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* for an upcoming campaign, I'm writing a few teasers about the world in preparation. I know that the ["dragon"](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_(coin)) is the local name for the gold coin minted in Waterdeep, but it has two sides - one showing a dragon, and one showing an old man with a beard.

My initial instinct is that it's probably Ahghairon, the first Open Lord of Waterdeep, and the dragon is Aurinax, but I've not been able to find anything to back this up as there don't appear to be any images of Ahghairon.

Does anybody know if there are any official sources that give an indication on who it's supposed to be?

[image: Image of a Waterdhavian "dragon" gold coin]

Answer (score 37):

I contacted the artist who [designed](https://olgadrebas.tumblr.com/post/178714776379/my-designs-of-assorted-waterdeep-coins-the-final) the coin pictured. Her name is Olga Drebas, and she is listed as one of the Interior Illustrators on page 2 of W:DH. In a [public tumblr post](https://olgadrebas.tumblr.com/post/182447731997/the-artwork-for-the-coins-you-did-is-beautiful) she answered:

> The character on the golden coin is Ahghairon, the first Open Lord and founder of Waterdeep city, as per the art brief I had.

For the record, Olga was very nice.